# nginx 504 timeout with php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I've scoured the internet and it seems like the only advice given to fix a  timeout with nginx/fpm is to increase the time, but my error isn't fixed when doing that for either. Chrome says `no data sent` after a really long time.

Everything was actually working fine until I installed xdebug (through aptitude) and added its configuration to the `php.ini` file and configured phpStorm with it. Not sure how related that could be.

I have a php file  that just has `Hello world` in it, so there aren't any long lived tasks. What else besides the script taking a long time could result in a timeout for nginx and phpfpm?

Comment: What time? Question is way too broad. What is going on with your script? We need more details.

Comment: I used values from 180 to 600 for both the fpm and nginx configs. As stated, the script only has `Hello World` in it. @NiCkNewman